# Sound Pool Load Listener?

Tags: android

I load a sound into soundpool and then:

```
mySoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                int status) {
            loaded = true;
        }
    });
```

My question is, how can I get the sound to play straight after it is loaded without the user having to do anything like touch a button?

Thanks

Comment: Include a call to `mySoundPool.play(...)` in the `onLoadComplete(...)` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListner(new OnLoadCompleteListner(){

@override
onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status)
{
    if(status == 0)
    soundPool.play(soundId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 0.0f);
}});
```